# Would a gamepad or joystick improve the handling of aircrafts in Just Cause 2 PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, just-cause-2

I love flying planes in Just Cause 2 but the keyboard controls are just binary so it's not very precise or "natural".

I wonder if I would really benefit from using a gamepad or joystick. Could I in particular have finer control of:

- thrust (you only have fast/slow with the keyboard)
- roll
- pitch

I do not currently own a gamepad (or joystick) so I'm thinking of buying one just for this game (on a Windows 8, 64-bit PC) but I won't if there's no real improvement.

Comment: Hello downvoter, why is this question bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

Yes.

#### Long answer

- Thrust is controlled using the analog trigger. The harder you pull it, the stronger you accelerate/brake.
- Roll and
- Pitch are both controlled using the analog sticks, giving you more precise control over your plane's movements.

Similar applies also to other vehicles and Rico himself.